# Formatting binary values in Scala

Tags: scala, string-formatting

Does Scala have a built in formatter for binary data?

For example to print out: 00000011 for the Int value 3.

Writing one won't be difficult - just curious if it exists.

Comment: It does. But they are limited, incomplete, or even return wrong results. For more details, see my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
scala> 3.toBinaryString
res0: String = 11
```

Scala has an implicit conversion from Int to RichInt which has a method toBinaryString. This function does not print the leading zeroes though.

Comment: I just added an answer that does print leading zeros. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113

Answer (score 22):

I don't know of a direct API method to do it, but here is one way of doing it:

```
def toBinary(i: Int, digits: Int = 8) =
    String.format("%" + digits + "s", i.toBinaryString).replace(' ', '0')
```

Comment: @JacobusR Thanks. Actually I believe that's what you asked about, since you were pretty clear in your question, asking for "a built in *formatter*", not converter!

Comment: The default value for `digits` should be `32` to accurately reflect the type of input, `Int`. Then, it is the caller's burden to take responsibility for providing any value below `32` as only the caller can assert that the value is small enough to fit in 8 bits (as the implementer, you cannot assume this).

Comment: And using post conversion `String` functions are more computationally expensive; i.e. `replace()`, than depending upon vastly faster bit and integer operations. While I do end up having to use `String` functions in my answer, they are required as a result of actual incorrect values being returned by the `toBinaryString()` methods in the Scala standard library. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113

Answer (score 10):

8 digits for number 3 with leading zeros:

```
printf ("%08d", 3.toBinaryString.toInt)
00000011
```

Since Hosam Aly suggests to create a String as well, here is a method to do so:

```
def asNdigitBinary (source: Int, digits: Int): String = {
  val l: java.lang.Long = source.toBinaryString.toLong
  String.format ("%0" + digits + "d", l) }
```

In the general case, using a Long is more appropriate, since binary values get long very fast:

```
scala> asNdigitBinary (1024*512-1, 32)
res23: String = 00000000000001111111111111111111
```

So keep that in mind - a selfmade, recursive approach which generates digit by digit and fills them up in the end would be easily made to handle arbitrary values of BigInt.

```
def toBinDigits (bi: BigInt): String = { 
  if (bi == 0) "0" else toBinDigits (bi /2) + (bi % 2)}

def fillBinary (bi: BigInt, len: Int) = { 
  val s = toBinDigits (bi)
  if (s.length >= len) s 
  else (List.fill (len-s.length) ("0")).mkString ("") + s
}
```

It would be nice, if

```
def asNdigitBinary (source: Int, digits: Int): String = {
  val l = BigInt (source.toBinaryString.toLong) 
  String.format ("%0" + digits + "d", l)}
```

would work, but "%0Nd" does not match for BigInt digits. Maybe a Bugreport/Feature request should be made? But to Scala or Java?

Comment: This is a good answer, except that it prints the result instead of storing it in a usable variable. You could try this instead:
`String.format("%08d", 3.toBinaryString.toInt.asInstanceOf[Object])`

Comment: @HosamAly: `For example to print out: 00000011 for the Int value 3.`

Comment: Good catch. :) Nevertheless, it would be valuable to add the generic version to your answer. I would have added it to mine, but I believe it's your idea.

Comment: I did so, but expanded it, to fit for larger values.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `toLong` means that this solution is limited to integer values < 524,288 (2^19).

Comment: The bug request needs to goto both Scala and Java. There are errors in both standard libraries for Byte and Short. you can see how I correct for there errors in my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113

Answer (score 6):

I usually use to prepend zeroes of the wanted length -1 and then just chop the rightmost characters:

```
"0000000" + 3.toBinaryString takeRight 8
```

This works fine for negative values as well.

Comment: Can also generalise to ("0" * width) + n.toBinaryString takeRight width

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more way (old Java):

```
val x = 5
val str = Integer.toString(x,2)
```

Just like Lauri answer, it doesn't print leading zeros.

Comment: I keep forgetting there is nothing evil about using Java in Scala

Comment: I just added a Scala way to consistently ensure leading zeros. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113

Answer (score 2):

The Scala standard library's built-in to-binary-digits `String` formatters (`toBinaryString`) for the integer types (`Byte`, `Short`, `Char`, `Int`, and `Long`) are very limited. And an implementation for `Boolean` isn't provided.

Additionally, for `Byte` and `Short`, the actual emitted format is wrong for negative values (as both forward to the `Int.toBinaryString` implementation which then `1` fills out to 32 characters, not the correct widths of 8 and 16 characters respectively).

Also, I have read through every answer here. And I learned quite a bit about the various ways to approach solving this problem. Ultimately, though, there wasn't a drop in solution which "just worked" within my current project. So...

I have created a single method implementation fixing and then enhancing all of the above inconsistencies, errors, and adds missing functionality.

The `size` parameter has three domains of values. See the code comments for more precise details.

1. `size = 0` -> (DEFAULT) zero fill to the bit size of the containing type
2. `size < 0` -> model the default behavior of toBinaryString function already on `Byte`, `Short`, `Char`, `Int`, and `Long` -  also fix the hidden upcast to `Int` for both `Byte` and `Short`
3. `size > 0` -> caller designated zero fill - ignored if the size is smaller than the length required to capture the `1` digit immediately to the left of the leftmost `0` digit (to preserve the sign)

---

```
    def toBinaryString[A <: AnyVal](value: A, size: Int = 0): String = {
      val zerosX64: String = //maximum possible number of leading zeros
        "0" * 64

      val (valueAsBinaryString, typeSize) =
        value match {
          case valueAlmostTyped: Boolean =>
            (if (valueAlmostTyped) "1" else "0", 1)
          case valueAlmostTyped: Byte =>
            (valueAlmostTyped.toByte.toBinaryString.takeRight(8), 8) //take() fixes hidden upcast to Int in Byte.toBinaryString
          case valueAlmostTyped: Short =>
            (valueAlmostTyped.toShort.toBinaryString.takeRight(16), 16) //take() fixes hidden upcast to Int in Short.toBinaryString
          case valueAlmostTyped: Char =>
            (valueAlmostTyped.toChar.toBinaryString, 16)
          case valueAlmostTyped: Int =>
            (valueAlmostTyped.toInt.toBinaryString, 32)
          case valueAlmostTyped: Long =>
            (valueAlmostTyped.toLong.toBinaryString, 64)
          case _ =>
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"toBinaryString not implemented for this type [${value.getClass.getSimpleName}] - only implemented for Boolean, Byte, Short, Char, Int, and Long")
        }
        
      val newSize =
        if (size < 0) //model and fix the behavior of existing toBinaryString function on Byte, Short, Char, Int, and Long, and add for Binary
          valueAsBinaryString.length
        else
          if (size == 0) //zero fill to the bit size of the containing type
            typeSize
          else
            if (valueAsBinaryString.length > size) //possibly override the caller specified custom size value as it is smaller than the resulting valueAsBinaryString itself
              if (valueAsBinaryString.take(valueAsBinaryString.length - size + 1).exists(_ == '0')) //only override if there isn't a zero dropped (which includes protecting the sign by ensuring if all 1s preceded the 0, at least a single one is preserved
                valueAsBinaryString.length
              else //caller specified custom value
                size
            else //caller specified custom value
              size
      ( (
            if (newSize > valueAsBinaryString.length)
              zerosX64.take(newSize - valueAsBinaryString.length)
            else
              ""
        )
        + valueAsBinaryString.takeRight(newSize)
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print the leading zeroes:

```
  def int2bin(i: Int, numPos: Int): String = {
    def nextPow2(i: Int, acc: Int): Int = if (i < acc) acc else nextPow2(i, 2 * acc)
    (nextPow2(i, math.pow(2,numPos).toInt)+i).toBinaryString.substring(1)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
scala> val x = 3
x: Int = 3

scala> Integer.toString(x, 2)
res4: java.lang.String = 11
```

As with other suggestions, this doesn't have leading zeros...

Comment: Here's the documentation for the Integer.toString(int i, int radix) method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-

Comment: I just added an answer that does print leading zeros. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113