# Bitwise right and left shift for large power

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

```
byte b = 5;
int n = 33;
b<<n
b>>n
```

I know how to calculate it: If this is a left shift, then we need to multiply the number by 2 to power n and for right shift we have to divide the number by 2 to power n.

If n is small number I can calculate. Can someone explain me how to calculate it manually if n is large (like here it's 33) or is there any other method?

Comment: I just added an answer to another thread for "printing the binary string" which works for `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Char`, `Int`, and `Long`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113

Answer (score 5):

If your right operand is larger than 31 then you can use a `long` instead of an `int`. Its values are between -2^63 and 2^63 - 1.

**And beware of `>>`, it does not do what you intuitively think it does**. It carries the sign bit!

For instance, on a short which reads:

```
1000 0101
```

right shifting by 3 will give the completely counterintuitive result:

```
1111 0001
```

instead of:

```
0001 0001
```

If you want "real" right shifting, use `>>>` instead.

If it is even bigger than that, you have to use a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
final BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("5");
```

`BigInteger` has `.shiftLeft()` and `.shiftRight()` methods (the equivalents of Java's `<<` and `>>>` -- note the triple `>` -- on integer primitive types). Note that these operations will return a **new** `BigInteger`! So, don't do:

```
b1.shiftLeft(33);
```

this will NOT affect the value of `b1`. Do:

```
final BigInteger b2 = b1.shiftLeft(33);
```

Comment: Uh, that is not what your question says at all :/

Comment: Not using any IDE like eclipse.

Comment: Eh? That has nothing to do!!

Comment: Just wondering why people think that Java is IDE-dependent. It is **not**!

Answer (score 3):

Use `long` instead of `byte`.

```
long b = 5;
int n = 33;
System.out.println(b<<n);//n should be between 0 to 63
System.out.println(b>>n);//since you are using long,the operation returns long
```

---

if left operand is **long**,the right operand should be between **0 to 63**

but if left operand is **not long**,the right operand should be between **0 to 31**

If your right operand can be bigger than 63, use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

---

**NOTE**

Only integral types(int,long,byte,short) are allowed as operands for shift operators

Answer (score 2):

Well, basically, you must know what shifting means.

If you have a number `5` which is represented in memory like `0000101` (bits; byte has 8 bits), to shift left (multiply) looks like this:

```
00000101 << 1 = 00001010 = 10 (decimal) //shifting bits to the left
00000101 << 3 = 00101000 = 40 (decimal)
```

to shift right (divide):

```
00000101 >> 1 = 00000010 = 2 (decimal) //shifting bits to the right
00000101 >> 3 = 00000000 = 0 (decimal)
```

So you could do it using the loop and a mathematical multiply / divide:

To shift left - multiply:

```
byte b= 5;
long number= (byte)b;
int n= 33;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    number= number * 2;
}

b = (byte)number;
```

Same goes for right, just divide instead of multiply in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Manually, you still have to multiply it by 2^n for a left shift. And guess what, to do it manually for a right shift, you still have to divide by 2^n and round down the result. So here is to do it manually in detail:

1. Take pen and paper.
2. Write down the number you want to shift.
3. Convert it to binary base representation.
4. Add `n` zeroes behind it.
5. Convert the number back.

Or if you don't want to use the binary representation:

1. Take pen and paper.
2. Write down the number you want to shift.
3. Calculate 2^n manually. It goes like: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4192, ...
4. Multiply the number by the one you just calculated using [this technique](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_bnlB2KRL4). It is called Long Multiplication.