# Converting a column from decimal to binary string in Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, number-systems

I have a Spark dataframe with decimal column. I want to convert this column to a binary string. Are there any function for this can anybody help?

Thank you!

Comment: I just added an answer to another thread for doing this (converting a value to a String of binary digits) which works for `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Char`, `Int`, and `Long`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [bin inbuilt function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#bin-java.lang.String-)  which states

> > `An expression that returns the string representation of the binary value of the given long column. For example, bin("12") returns "1100".`

So if you have a dataframe as

```
+-----+
|Value|
+-----+
|4    |
+-----+

root
 |-- Value: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)
```

You can use `bin` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
data.withColumn("Value_Binary", bin(col("Value")))
```

which should give you

```
+-----+------------+
|Value|Value_Binary|
+-----+------------+
|4    |100         |
+-----+------------+

root
 |-- Value: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- Binary_value: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with creating a user defined function.

```
val toBinStr: Int => String = _.toBinaryString

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val toBinStrUDF = udf(toBinStr)

// Apply the UDF to change the source dataset
data.withColumn("Value_Binary", toBinStrUDF($"Value")).show
```

Comment: Yours only works with `Int`. I just added an answer to another thread for doing this (converting a value to a String of binary digits) which works for `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Char`, `Int`, and `Long`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950845/501113